# How to get HTTP/2 working with an IIS-hosted ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, http2, kestrel-http-server

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/protocols?view=aspnetcore-6.0, **HTTP/2** should just work by default when running an ASP.NET Core app in IIS using SSL.

Despite this, all responses are sent using HTTP1.1 instead. Could it be that IIS is maybe sending everything to Kestrel over *http* instead of *https*?

[image]

When running the app without IIS, the first log rows look like this:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

But these are missing when running under IIS. I know Kestrel will refuse to use HTTP/2 if requests aren't made over https.
Instead it just starts with this:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: <path>
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://tax/ - -
```

What am I missing?

---

Bindings for the site:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis#when-is-http2-not-supported There are quite a few not supported cases, so unless you edit the question to reveal more information, it cannot be discussed further.

Comment: Neither of those three are applicable to me. What more information would you like?

Comment: Then let your browser give you detailed logs on how HTTP/2 negotiation fails, https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/for-testers/providing-network-details

Comment: Using out-of-process hosting? Docs say: Public-facing edge server connections use HTTP/2, but the reverse proxy connection to the Kestrel server uses HTTP/1.1